# If a diverging sequence has a convergent subsequence, does it always have another subsequence that converges to a different limit?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I have a question about subsequences of a sequence in a metric space.
let $X$ be a metric space and $(x_n)$ be a diverging sequence in $X$. Suppose $(x_n)$ has a subsequence with a limit $a \in X.$ Does it hold true that there exists a subsequence of $(x_n)$ such that it has a limit $b \in X$, $b \neq a$?

Comment: No, unless $X$ is compact.  For example, the sequence $0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,\dots$ has only one limit point $0\in\mathbb{R}$ (but of course it has the other limit point $+\infty\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ that is not in $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 3):

That assertion holds if and only if $X$ is compact. In fact:

- If $X$ is compact, then every sequence has a convergent subsequence. So, every divergent sequence has a convergent subsequence.
- If $X$ is not compact, then it has a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ with no convergent sequence. So, if $x\in X$, the sequence$$x,x_1,x,x_2,x,x_3,\ldots$$has a convergent subsequence, but it has no subsequence that converges to a different limit.